# Is parameterized constructor (Java) supported in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, java

I was asked in an interview whether Selenium Webdriver supported parameterized constructors.

Example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public   class Cons {
        public  String username="u";
        public  String pswd="p";
        public  String baseurl="url";
        public  WebDriver d;

public  Cons(String username, String pswd){
            d = new FirefoxDriver();
            d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            d.get(baseurl);
                d.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(this.username);
                d.findElement(By.name("pwd")).sendKeys(this.pswd);
              }
 }
```

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: why would you want this?

Comment: Hello Erki, I was faced this question in interview.

Comment: @QA4it - I edited the question to mention that you were asked this in an interview.

Comment: @Kate Paulk - Ok, sir.

Comment: @QA4it - Well, this question has nothing to do with Selenium WebDriver, rather with Java or test framework (JUnit, TestNG). Could you please edit the title and tags?

Comment: @dziecious -I dont feel i need to edit this because i used it in webdriver code.. If i not use webdriver then i can say this is not related with webdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, We can write webdriver code in constructor as well. I tried to create an example with your given code. Hope this helps !

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test { 

public String baseurl="http://aavtrain.com/";
public WebDriver d;

public Test(String username, String pswd)
{ 
d = new FirefoxDriver();
d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
d.get(baseurl); 
d.findElement(By.name("user_name")).sendKeys(username);
d.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pswd);
}

  public static void main(String aregs[])
  {
    Test t=new Test("abc","cde");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is GREAT answer and solution for me my friend... Really very thank to you.. AWESOME :) ...